# High memory usage with bufferedreader and websites

Tags: java, multithreading, url, memory, bufferedreader

I've written a program which connects to websites and gets the title of the webpage. I get the URLs from a text which can be inserted in the program and then all the urls are in a list. To speed the things up I use multiple threads. If I have for example 10 Threads and 10 URLs my program uses about 100 MB memory. But if I have 5 Threads and 10 URLs, so that each thread has to connect to two websites my memory usage goes up to about 1,3 GB. I've found that it is the one line in the code which makes my program use so much memory:

```
in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(spoof.getInputStream()));
```

which is in this method:

```
private BufferedReader in;
private URL url;
private URLConnection spoof;

private void openConnection() {

    try {
        url = new URL(tag.url);
        spoof = url.openConnection();
        spoof.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", userAgent);

        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(spoof.getInputStream()));

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        tag.ableToConnect = false;
    }
}
```

I tried to close the BufferedReader and run a manual `System.gc()`. Both with no effect on the memory usage.

I would be happy if you could help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I have for example 10 Threads and 10 URLs my program uses about 100 MB memory.

Couple of general comments.

1. There certainly is no problem with having 10 (or 100) `BufferedReader` objects existing at any point in time.  The default buffer size is 8k chars or 16k bytes.  100 of them would be a couple of megs.  Each thread should be reading from one `BufferedReader` at a time and you should `close()` and set to `null` (see below) the `in` in a `try {} finally {}` block to make sure that you properly release the memory, even in the case of `IOException`.
2. If the memory leak is indeed with the `BufferedReader` then you are are obviously keeping references to them somehow.  Calling `close()` on it is not enough because it will not release the underlying buffers.  You should set the `in` field and other places where they are referenced to be `null` to make sure that GC can reap it.  Maybe the class that is holding on to the `BufferedReader` is kept around in a collection or something?
3. One thing to consider is to restrict the number of outstanding URLs in the queue.  Knowing how large the URL queue gets may inform you about the amount of memory being kept in the queue itself.  You might consider just having a queue of `String` instead of `URL` or anything more heavy.  Limiting the size of the queue won't work perfectly because it will stop your threads from processing the pages and may even cause a deadlock.

Answer (score 0):

1)Try inputstreamreader
2)Dont  try to read all chunk read by line

```
public class BufferedReaderExample {   

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        //reading file line by line in Java using BufferedReader       
        FileInputStream fis = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;

        try {
            fis = new FileInputStream("C:/sample.txt");
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));

            System.out.println("Reading File line by line using BufferedReader");

            String line = reader.readLine();
            while(line != null){
                System.out.println(line);
                line = reader.readLine();
            }           

        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(BufferedReaderExample.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(BufferedReaderExample.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);

        } finally {
            try {
                reader.close();
                fis.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(BufferedReaderExample.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
  }
```

Read more: http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2012/07/read-file-line-by-line-java-example-scanner.html#ixzz2jVVs2RMN 
If speed turns out to be a problem, you could have a look at the [java.nio][1] packages - those are supposedly faster than java.io,

Comment: `BufferedReader.close` will close the reader it is passed to.

Comment: I read if line by line in another method. I just open the connection in the one I posted.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure it will help, but you should also close the InputStreamReader.

Comment: `BufferedReader.close` will close the reader it is passed to.

Comment: I have another method which reads the title from the source code of the website. At the end of this method I close the BufferedReader.

Comment: BufferedReader.close maybe does close the InputStreamReader, but the  documentation is does not say so: "Closes the stream and releases any system resources associated with it." It does not say it closes the reader, I take it to mean that it releases the association to the reader, i.e. nullifies or releases any references to it.

Comment: `BufferedReader` _definitely_ closes the underlying reader.  The docs may not specifically say so but the code does. `if (in == null) return; in.close();`

Comment: In this case, FindBugs should have been amended. However, I think we should follow the spec rather than the implementation.